# How to call .ASCX in site.Master page in web form application

Tags: asp.net

I have created .ASCX control for registration and login and has given reference in site.master. When clicked on login then login pop up should appear and the same for registration.If i put `<uc:Login ID="ucLogin" runat="server" />`  code first then Login works and registration does not and the vice-versa. I think the problem is here:

```
<uc:Login ID="ucLogin" runat="server" /> 
<uc1:Registration ID="Registration" runat="server"  />
```

I do not know whether it is good to put `<uc1:Registration ID="Registration" runat="server"/>` under  `<asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled"`> The whole site.Master page looks like this:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

    <%@ Register Src = "~/Controls/Login.ascx" TagName = "Login" TagPrefix = "uc" %>
    <%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Registration.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Registration" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head runat="server">

        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">

        </asp:PlaceHolder>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">

            </asp:ScriptManager>

                        <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                            <AnonymousTemplate>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                                    <li>  <uc:Login ID="ucLogin" runat="server" />     </li>
                                    <li> <uc1:Registration ID="Registration" runat="server"  /></li>
                                </ul>

                            </AnonymousTemplate>
                          </asp:LoginView>  

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container body-content">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <hr />

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the Login.ascx is:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.ascx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">


    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" CssClass="col-md-3 control-label">User name</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-3 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="LogIn" Text="Log in" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

</asp:Panel>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" DropShadow="false"
    TargetControlID="lnkLogin" PopupControlID="pnlLogin"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The registration.ascx page looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Registration.ascx.cs" Inherits="Registration" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc11" %>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRegistration" runat="server" Text="Registration"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlRegistration" runat="server">

    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="EmailId" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Email Address</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="EmailId" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailId" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Register" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

</asp:Panel>

<cc11:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup1" runat="server" DropShadow="false"
    TargetControlID="lnkRegistration" PopupControlID="pnlRegistration"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="lnkCancel">
</cc11:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You have not included an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review that page and edit your question until it fulfills all of the MCVE criteria.

Comment: @mason, I have removed unwanted code. Can you please have a look. Please provide me some solutions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you read the link I provided you? You still have not fulfilled all of the MCVE criteria. Please review.

Comment: @mason, I have made so much changes in the questions. Please go through the code and provide me the solutions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's better, although it's not Minimal. Did you look in the JavaScript console in the browser for errors? Does the page postback when you click on the buttons?

Comment: @mason, No, it does not postback.If i place registration before login then registration works but login does not. Can you please tell me whether can i write <uc:Login ID="ucLogin" runat="server" /> 
<uc1:Registration ID="Registration" runat="server"  /> in same site.master. If so then, i can write these both under <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">

Comment: Of course you can have two custom controls on your page. Did you check the JavaScript console like I told you?

Comment: @mason, Yes i checked JavaScript console. When the page loads it throws error : Cannot read property '_events' of null. But nothing is happening when i click on Registration  and login link.

Comment: Hi there, is there anyone who can guide me to resolve my issues? I do not understand why i am not able to click the link. Nothing is happening. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the problem is you were asked to "create .ASCX control", where everything in that quote is singular. Instead, you created *two* controls (plural). Better to do one control, like this:

In master:

```
<%@ Register Src = "~/Controls/LoginRegister.ascx" TagName = "LoginRegister" TagPrefix = "uc" %>

...


<asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <uc:LoginRegister ID="ucLogin" runat="server" /> 
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

And then in the new combined loginregister.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.ascx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc" %>

<ul>
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:LinkButton></li>
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRegistration" runat="server" Text="Registration"></asp:LinkButton></li>
<ul>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlLogin" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email" CssClass="col-md-3 control-label">User name</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                CssClass="text-danger" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-3 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="LogIn" Text="Log in" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlRegistration" runat="server">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="EmailId" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Email Address</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="EmailId" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailId" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Password</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="CreateUser_Click" Text="Register" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>

<cc:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" DropShadow="false"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Where you also update the *.cs file so the new control so the postback from the links sets the right fields for PopUpExtender.  Or, even better, you re-write that part to use javascript (and only javascript) to show the correct panel, such that no server event is needed until the user pushes the login or register buttons.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It solved my problem. Thank you once again.